# My React Typescript app is showing an blank page with errors when hosted at firebase

Tags: firebase, react-typescript, manifest.json

Well, I have a React typescript app which I am hosting at firebase but when I open it up it shows a blank page with some errors. It looks like the error is regarding Manifest.json but can't get it.

The errors:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.4e369b22.js:1:1) manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.`

And this is my `manifest.json`:

```
{

  "short_name": "Pritam's portfolio",

  "name": "made with ReactJS",

  "icons": [

    {

      "src": "profilePic.jpg",

      "type": "image/png",

      "sizes": "512x512"

    }

  ],

  "start_url": ".",

  "display": "standalone",

  "theme_color": "#000000",

  "background_color": "#ffffff"

}
```

And my `package.json`:

```
{

  "name": "portfolio",

  "homepage": "https://pritam-4efd0.web app/portfolio/",

  "version": "0.1.0",

  "private": true,

  "dependencies": {

    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",

    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",

    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",

    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",

    "@types/node": "^16.18.58",

    "@types/react": "^18.2.28",

    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.13",

    "axios": "^1.5.1",

    "everyday-fun": "^1.1.0",

    "jest": "^27.5.1",

    "react": "^18.2.0",

    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",

    "react-pdf": "^7.6.0",

    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",

    "typescript": "^4.9.5",

    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"

  },

  "scripts": {

    "dev": "react-scripts start",

    "build": "react-scripts build",

    "test": "jest",

    "eject": "react-scripts eject",

    "format": "prettier --write ./* --config ./.prettierrc.json --ignore-path ./.prettierignore"

  },

  "eslintConfig": {

    "extends": [

      "react-app",

      "react-app/jest"

    ]

  },

  "browserslist": {

    "production": [

      ">0.2%",

      "not dead",

      "not op_mini all"

    ],

    "development": [

      "last 1 chrome version",

      "last 1 firefox version",

      "last 1 safari version"

    ]

  },

  "devDependencies": {

    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",

    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",

    "postcss": "^8.4.31",

    "prettier": "^3.0.3",

    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"

  }

}
```

Well I tried using the devtools to find out what's wrong, but I could not make it out...

[Here](https://pritam-4efd0.web.app/) is my firebase hosting link.

Please help..